# How do you get the ID of a row in a Core Data entity, such that you can reference it later?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7

Small question!

With Ruby on Rails (which I appreciate talks to a "real" database), with each record I add to a table, I can extract the ID of that record, send it somewhere, do something with it, and return data which can be associated with the original record.

I can't (for the life of me) seem to find the way to do it in Core Data.

If I have a Messages Entity with rows of messages. I want to be able to extract the ID of the message (row ID?), and send it to my server, and have a response change the same record by looking up it's ID.

The closest I can get is `[message objectID]`. However, I have no idea what this really returns, and I can't seem to encode it in a JSON request anyway.

Sigh.

Any help would be appreciated as I really don't know where to start with this one.

**Edit:**

Looking at other websites, and finally drilling it down, I've decided to use my own Unique ID. Apple can change the structure of URIRepresentation and, objectID can change if you change the structure of core data. So, it's best to stick with what I know.

Comment: objectID is a unique id for an object in CoreData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at other websites, and finally drilling it down, I've decided to use my own Unique ID. Apple can change the structure of URIRepresentation and, objectID can change if you change the structure of core data. So, it's best to stick with what I know.

Answer (score 0):

objectID is a unique id for an object in CoreData. Quoted from Apple

> An NSManagedObjectID object is a compact, universal identifier for a
>   managed object. This forms the basis for uniquing in the Core Data
>   Framework. A managed object ID uniquely identifies the same managed
>   object both between managed object contexts in a single application,
>   and in multiple applications (as in distributed systems). Identifiers
>   contain the information needed to exactly describe an object in a
>   persistent store (like the primary key in the database), although the
>   detailed information is not exposed. The framework completely
>   encapsulates the “external” information and presents a clean object
>   oriented interface.

you might consider reading the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/Reference/NSManagedObjectID.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectID)

You can get an URIRepresentation which might help you with JSON representation.

Comment: You can use the objectID as a unique identifier as soon as the object was persisted. The ID may vary shortly after the object was crated while it is still transient.

Comment: I perhaps didn't phrase the questions well enough. I've read the docs over and over again ... but to no avail. I'm on the case however and will keep trying. I know objectID is a way to go ... but can't encode the information in a JSON form. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Why can't you use objectID or URIRepresentation ? Maybe you elaborate why these two won't work for you.

Comment: Apparently, according to lots of blogs other there, Apple have the right to change `URIRepresentation` at any time (but still maintain previous versions). This, alongside the fact that ObjectID can change if you migrate or change the structure of the entity etc, means it's just not worth the effort or risk. I've followed other advice, and created my own unique ID and will search on that instead. Them when I change the structure, it won't break things (I hope!).